# Using PHP how I can print a string reverse

Tags: php

I want to print the string reversed. I found this code but I can't understand what is the meaning of immediate two line after the for loop.

```
<?php 
    $s = 'abcdefg';
    $j = 0;

    for ($i = strlen($s) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
       $s .= $s[$i];
       $s[$i] = NULL;
       $j++;
    }
    echo "$s";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "there are " . $j . " character in the string.";
?>
```

Comment: which lines do you mean?!

Answer (score 6):

Just simply use [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

```
<?php
echo strrev("abcdefg");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s .= $s[$i];
```

This line will be generating the reverse string and concatenating it with the variable `$s`. And since you are concatenating this variable `$s` (which already has some value `abcdefg`, you need to remove each characters from the variable which is done by the following line in your code:

```
$s[$i] = NULL;
```

You can check this by removing this line and check the output. It will output:

> abcdefggfedcba

The simpler alternative would be to use [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function

Answer (score -1):

follow this code

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);

    $s = 'abcdefg';
    $length = strlen($s);
    $k=array();
    for ($i = $length; $i>=0; $i--) {
       $k .= $s[$i];
       $k[$i] = NULL;

     }
    echo "$s";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "there are <b>".$k."</b> character in the string.";
?>
```